# Python with Pandas--Unable to read a CSV file from a URL

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, linear-regression

After importing the following libraries, I am trying to read a CSV file from [here.](https://github.com/marcopeix/ISL-linear-regression/blob/master/data/Advertising.csv)

```
    `import pandas as pd
     import numpy as np
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
     from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
     import statsmodels.api as sm
     from pandas.core import datetools`

    `data = pd.read_csv("https://github.com/marcopeix/ISL-linear-` 
     regression/blob/master/data/Advertising.csv", sep='delimiter', 
     header=None,` `engine='python')`
```

May I please request someone to explain the reason why I am  getting HTML tags as output..

```
`data.head(5)`

  ` 0
    0   <!DOCTYPE html>
    1   <html lang="en">
    2   <head>
    3   <meta charset="utf-8">
    4   <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://assets-...`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the Github page, you will find `Raw` in the right end as shown in screenshot below. Click the Raw and copy the url of that.

[image]

**Here is the right url for you:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/marcopeix/ISL-linear-regression/master/data/Advertising.csv")
```

Comment: It made sense. Thanks a lot!